# Initialisation lists for constructors

Tags: c++

```
struct C {
    C() { cout << "constructor C called\n"; }
};

struct A {
    A() { cout << "constructor A called\n"; }
};

struct B {
    A A_;
    C C_;

    B() : C_(), A_() { cout << "constructor B is called\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    B Michael;
}
```

What is the purpose of initialisation lists?
I understand that when an instance of a class is created, the constructors for the member variables are called. I have read somewhere that initialisation lists can control the order of which member constructor is called first. In the bellow code the output is:

```
constructor A called
constructor C called
constructor B is called
```

This order is the order of declaration of the member variables.
What is the significance of `B() : C_(), A_()`?

Comment: In this particular example, the initializer list is redundant. Imagine though that constructors for `C` and `A` take parameters - how is `B`'s constructor going to provide them?

Comment: *I have read somewhere that initialisation lists can control the order of which member constructor is called first.* – Nope. Members are initialized in the order they are declared in the class.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Lets consider that they do provide parameters to the constructors A and C. Is there constructor for classes A and C then called twice? Once for the declaration and 2nd for the parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure what "once for the declaration" even means. No, constructors are not called twice. Why don't you test it and see for yourself?

Comment: @ Igor Tandetnik I see that they are called once with the parameters provided.
But if the member constructors are called first before the class constructor, then there must either be a constructor called twice?

Comment: Constructors of the members are called **because** a class/struct gets instantiated. The initializer-list **is** before the constructor of the class/struct runs. After the constructors of the members, the constructor of the class/struct containing them runs. Nothing twice.

Comment: Why must there be a constructor called twice? I don't understand what you are trying to say, sorry.

Comment: Ok, lets say i instantiate the class B, what constructors are called first? The members? Afterwards initialisation list followed by constructor body of class B?
So what is the purpose of B() : C_(), A_() because this is called after the member constructors?

Comment: You guys are obviously not experts: 
It is explained clearly here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nfuYMXjZsA

Comment: Take notes @IgorTandetnik, constructor is called twice:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change the example slightly

```
struct C {
    C(const std::string & name) :myName(name){ cout << "constructor C called\n"; }
private:
    std::string myName;
};
```

Now you are forced to provide a `string` when you construct a `C` because as soon as you specify a custom constructor, the compiler-generated default constructor goes away. There is only one way to construct a `C` and it must be given a `string`.

Before the body of `B`'s constructor can be entered all of its members and base classes must be fully constructed. Since there is no default constructor for `C` the only option is to use the initializer list.

In addition, sometimes the construction of an object is expensive. If you default construct this expensive object and then have to perform an expensive assignment (and possibly yet another construction to get a temporary object to assign) in the body of the containing class's constructor, you probably did a lot more work than was necessary.

```
class X
{
    dang_expensive ouch;
public:
    X(Param param) // ouch constructed. big cost
    {
        ouch = dang_expensive(param); // temp constructed and assigned 
                                      // maybe two big costs
    }
};
```

vs

```
class X
{
    dang_expensive ouch;
public:
    X(Param param) : ouch(param)// ouch constructed. big cost
    {
    }
};
```

Compilers are really sharp these days and will minimize this hit as much as possible. It's very possible that the compiler will be able to eliminate it entirely if there are no visible side effects.

Side note:

> I have read somewhere that initialisation lists can control the order of which member constructor is called first.

What you have read is incorrect.

```
struct B {
    A A_;
    C C_;

    B() : C_(), A_() { cout << "constructor B is called\n"; }
};
```

will still construct `A_` first because it was declared first. This sounds insane, but it provides hard guarantees on construction and ultimately destruction order that the compiler and the program as a whole can take advantage of. Some members may not be in the initializer list for some constructors. They will be initialized in the same order regardless. There are absolutely no surprises and a lack of surprises is a good thing when dealing with a computer. Modern compilers often warn you, if you have the warning level up high enough, when you have the list out of order because something like

```
B() : C_(), A_(C_) {}
```

can put your program in a world of hurt. Never ignore compiler warnings.

[Good documentation on Member Initializer Lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: *This sounds insane* – It sounds actually quite logical: There is only one place where a member is defined but there can be a number of constructors with initialization lists.

Comment: I have once question to clear everything up, 
C C_;
B() : C_("string"){ cout << "constructor B is called\n"; }
Will C C_ still call the default constructor?

Comment: Is it correct to say that the initialiser list overrides the member constructor call?

Comment: Does C_("string") even call the constructor of C?

Comment: @AskJheeze *Will C C_ still call the default constructor?* after the `C(const std::string & name)` modification there is no default constructor unless you explicitly add one. *Is it correct to say that the initialiser list overrides the member constructor call?* I'd say it replaces a default construction, if there is one available. One of the things Swordfish hints at is you don't have to put everything on the initializer list. The constructors will run anyway.

Comment: `C_("string")` will convert the `"string"` into a string and call the `C(const std::string & name)` constructor. You can have many constructors covering many different initialization cases. [Look at all the different ways you can construct a string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)!

Comment: @Swordfish good point. I need to clean up my wording there quite a bit.